# In JavaFX executable jar file popUp stages seems that do not read CSS file

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx, executable-jar

In JavaFX executable jar file of my application, popUp stages seems that do not read CSS file. They appear with default layout, while in eclipse IDE they load CSS stylesheet correctly without any exceptions.
Here is in eclipse IDE:
[Run application in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1j1D.png)

Here is with executable jar file:
[Run with executable jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQNMU.png)

Why this difference? Thanks for the eventual answer.

Comment: Do you see any warning about missing CSS and/or is the respective CSS file part of the executable jar? Further it would help if you could post the segment where you reference the CSS for your popups.

Comment: In addition to @hotzst's comments, you should also check you are running with the same version of the JRE in both cases.

Comment: How can i see warning about missing CSS running executable jar?

Comment: @James_D i am running with same version in the eclipse run as well as in the build.xml to create javaFX executable jar.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter such issue but i solved it by 
adding the following code where i applied the executable jar file.

This might be not a good solution. Hence, i would like to hear if there is any effective method.
ps: my executable jar file is only contain dialog pane's features and layout. Besides, the css can only work for **class selector** instead of id selector.
**dialog.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add(
          getClass().getResource("/com/abc/mycss.css").toExternalForm());**